# complex json parsing not found exception java

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have a json parser which parses a complex json object. Some object have key 'a2' and some don't. I want to return "not found" when the object doesn't have key "a2". Here is my code :

```
String JSON = {"IP":{"string":"1.2.3.4"},"rrr":{"test":{"a1":"36","a2":"www.abc.com"}}}

public String getParameters(JSONObject json) throws JSONException {

    String jsonString;
    if ((jsonString = json.getJSONObject("rrr").getJSONObject("test")
            .getString("a2")) != null) {
        return jsonString;
    } else
        return "not Found";

        }
```

But what is happening in the code is, if the parser doesn't find 'a2' it throws an exception and it returns. What changes do I make to the code to make it work?

Comment: You should include the full exception message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of `getTYPE(key)` methods, they will throw exception if `key` element wouldn't be found.

To avoid this you can use `optTYPE(key)` which in this case will return `null` or some default value.
In case of `optString` it will return empty String as default value, but you can use `optString(key, null)` to specify that you would rather it to return `null` if `key` element will not exist.

So your code can look like

```
public String getParameters(JSONObject json) throws JSONException {

    String jsonString;
    if ((jsonString = json.getJSONObject("rrr").getJSONObject("test")
            .optString("a2",null)) != null) {
    //       ^^^            ^^^^ <- default value in case of lack of element
        return jsonString;
    } else
        return "not Found";

}
```

Comment: @user2942227 Which one do you mean? If you mean [previous versions of my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28641998/revisions) then at first I added some mechanisms to also check for other keys like `rrr` but since your question was only about `getString` I simplified it a little. Anyway rule is the same `optXXX(key)` can return some default value if key will not be found while `getXXX(key)` will throw exception.